# Emulator: Warning: QXcbIntegration

Tags: android, android-emulator

When i run Android Emulator from Android Studio, i get this Warning:

> Emulator: Warning: QXcbIntegration: Cannot create platform
>   OpenGL context, neither GLX nor EGL are enabled ((null):0, (null))

This warning didn't appear before. What this warning is for and should i ignore it or not? What is the Fix for it?

Answer (score 0):

With `hw.gpu.mode = host` it seems to run with hardware OpenGLES emulation:

```
emulator: CPU Acceleration: working
emulator: CPU Acceleration status: KVM (version 12) is installed and usable.
Warning: QXcbIntegration: Cannot create platform OpenGL context, neither GLX nor EGL are enabled ((null):0, (null))
...

emulator: GPU emulation enabled using 'host' mode
emulator: Initializing hardware OpenGLES emulation support
emulator: VERBOSE: emulator-qt-window.cpp:2824: setUIMultiDisplay id 0 0 0 1080 2220 add
```

Either wait until the next version of the emulator will be released - or downgrade < `29.2.1`.

Comment: not working..... i have >glxinfo | grep "OpenGL version"
>OpenGL version string: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 430.26

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:192727%20status:open%20QXcbIntegration ... this is about emulator version `29.2.1`, which is required for some newer images. the previous emulator with previous images should still work.